# jQuery: Accumulating loop bug, unsure of source, code & console included

Tags: jquery

**What I'm trying to do:**

When an `<li>` element having two specific attributes (`data-model` and `data-state`) is clicked, a function should collect the `data-id` attribute of every `<li>` element with two specific data-attributes and collapse them into a string to become part of an ajax call.

**What's Going Wrong**

Whenever the function fires, it goes on to fire increasingly more times based on it's been called so far (this utterly confuses me, see my console print-out below).

Also, `.toggleClass()` is getting called repeatedly (and increasingly often), so it's not simply that `activeDomains` is accumulating. I'm just totally, totally stumped on this one—if there's any information needed, let me know. If it matters, I'm developing with CakePHP but using primarily external JS documents or buffered scripts (ie. `$this->Js-buffer()`) instead of Cake's JsHelper proper.

**My Code**

*Note: To avoid namespace collisions, I'm using [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), hence $j*

```
$j( 'li[data-model="domain"][data-state=0]').click( function() {
    var controller = "subjects";
    var action = "fetchByDomain";

    //inspect and toggle state
    $j(this).toggleClass("selected").attr("data-state", 1);

    //collect list of domains to send to subjects controller
    var activeDomains = [];
    $j('li[data-model="domain"][data-state=1]').each(function () { activeDomains.push(  $j(this).attr("data-id"))});

    console.log(activeDomains); //see output below

    //reload #subjectsList, WWW, APP, & DS are defined globally
    $j("#subjectList").load(WWW + APP + DS + controller + DS + action + DS + activeDomains.join(","));
});
```

**Associated HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <div id="domainList" class="row">
            <ul>
                <li data-id="2" data-parentid="-1" data-model="domain" data-state=0 class="module-filter">English</li>
                <li data-id="5" data-parentid="-1" data-model="domain" data-state=0 class="module-filter">Fine Arts</li>
                <li data-id="3" data-parentid="-1" data-model="domain" data-state=0 class="module-filter">Mathematics</li>
                <li data-id="1" data-parentid="-1" data-model="domain" data-state=0 class="module-filter">Psychology</li>
                <li data-id="4" data-parentid="-1" data-model="domain" data-state=0 class="module-filter">Sociology</li>            
            </ul>
     </div>
     <div id="subjectList" class="row"></div>
     <div id="excerptList" class="row"></div>
</div>
```

**Console Output**

Supposing I have 5 list elements with `data-id` values from 1-5, this is the output over time:

Click `<li data-id=1>`:

["1"]

Click `<li data-id=2>`:

["1","2"]

["1","2"]

Click (again) `<li data-id=2>`:

["1","2"]

["1","2"]

*Here's where—to me at least!—it gets really wierd:*

Click `<li data-id=3>`:

["1","2","3"]

["1","2","3"]

["1","2","3"]

["1","2","3"]

["1","2","3"]

["1","2","3"]

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: it is because once you click on a `li` you are changing the `data-state` to 1, so in the first click there is only one element with `data-state=1`, but when you click the second element you have the current and previous elements because you are not changing the value of the previous element to `0`

Comment: demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/djrWy/)

Comment: also can you clarify the desired value of `activeDomains`, do you want only the current `li`s value here

Comment: Well, that's intended—any or all of them can be in an active state, and the more that become active, the more the call to `$("subjectList").load()` should be bearing. But, what I don't understand is why the entire function gets called in a loop. If I click on one `<li>`, does that cause this function to fire for every element that matches my selector?

Comment: Re: clarification

Sure thing. Basically this is supposed to be a way of filtering hierarchically; every time a domain is turned on or off, the subjects div should be repopulated with all the new subset (ie. every domain has many subjects, every subject belongs to one domain). Does that help? I'm using the `activeDomains` array as a quick way of collecting the arguments for the call to `subjects/fetchByDomain/arg1,arg2,arg3`. (also thanks for taking the time to help man, hugely appreciated!)

Comment: the problem is in the like `$j('li[data-model="domain"][data-state=1]')`, it iterates through all `li` with `data-state=1`. Since you are setting `data-state=1` when clicking on an element the first click works fine, when you click on the second element there are two elements with `data-state=1`

Comment: ahhhhhh. So, if I understand you, just making my code into a defined function, giving each `<li>` and id, and adding an `onclick` attribute to the individual `<li>` items should solve?

Comment: dont know why. but it fine for me. view demo http://jsfiddle.net/apFn5/

Answer (score 0):

You can make `activeDomains` global like your others variables and replace

```
$j('li[data-model="domain"][data-state=1]').each(function () { activeDomains.push(  $j(this).attr("data-id"))});
```

with

```
activeDomains.push($(this).attr("data-id"));
```